# Cartesian product notation

Tags: notation

I have a question regarding a number of sets $\cal{X_i} \subset \mathbb{N}$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$ which are all containing a different number of elements and from which I build the cartesian product like

$\cal{Y} =  \cal{X_1} \times \cal{X_2} \times \dots \times \cal{X_n}$ .

The question is, whether one can say that $\cal{Y} \subset \mathbb{N}^n$ holds?  So the question concerns the notation of the space to which the set $\mathcal{Y}$ belongs.

Thank yo very much in advance!

Comment: What are the elements of $\mathbb{N}^n?$ What are the elements of $\cal{Y} =  \cal{X_1} \times \cal{X_2} \times \dots \times \cal{X_n}?$ Is it important the number of elements?

Comment: In general, if $A_k \subset B_k$ then $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n \subset B_1 \times \cdots \times B_n$.

Comment: Hi, the elements of $\cal{Y}$ are tuples of length $n$, like $(x_1,...,x_n)$. So the number of elements in a particular $\cal{X_i}$ is not important to define the space to which $\cal{Y}$ belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say $\mathcal{Y}\in\Bbb{N}^n$.

In general, by the definition of a Cartesian product, if

$$a\subseteq A \ \ \ \ \  b\subseteq B \ \ \ \ \ \cdots \ \ \ \ \ z\subseteq Z$$

then you can say

$$a × b \times \cdots × z \  \subseteq \  A × B × \cdots × Z$$

because it is *defined* that

$$A × B × \cdots × Z \ = \ \left\{ (\alpha,\beta,\cdots,\zeta) : \alpha\in A \wedge \beta\in B \wedge \cdots \wedge \zeta\in Z\right\}$$